# Bitbucket webhook is triggering all the Jenkins jobs for the repository?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, git-webhooks, bitbucket-webhook

I have created a Bitbucket webhook to trigger the jenkins jobs when a change is pushed to the repository. There are several different project in the repository and for each project a **separate Jenkins Job** is configured.

```
Webhook URL goes like this: 
http://10.230.0.14:8080/git/notifyCommit?url=ssh://git@bitbucket.abc.com:7999/scm/bitbucket.git
```

If a change is pushed to one of the many projects in the repository, all the Jenkins jobs are getting triggered which are subscribed to that repository.
I want to trigger only the job pertaining to the project, not all jobs belonging to the repository.

For an example, in repository **Rep1**, there are two folders: **Solution1** & **Solution2**.
Both folders have separate Jenkins jobs configured. When any change is pushed to folder **Solution1**, jenkins jobs related to **Solution1** should only be triggered, not **Solution2**.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: A Webhook will trigger in every push, as long as I am aware of it's possible to only trigger it for certain directory in bitbucket. I think the easiest way to achieve what you want is to break the folders in different repositories. A harder way was to inspect the commit in jenkins and decide if it should build or not (I wouldn't go there though).

Comment: My project requirement is like that we are managing all the projects in one repository. I want to achieve this something like one repository multiple webhooks for each directory.